# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 stuck on boot menu

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, usb-installation, syslinux

I want to use Linux for the first time a requirement for my masters program. I have bought a laptop Lenovo T580 which came installed with Windows 10. My disk partition type is GPT and NTFS file system. I have downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 and created a bootable Ubuntu  drive  using this  [instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Upon restarting windows and pressing <kbd>f12</kbd> for boot menu then xlicking `usb hdd` , nothing happens.  The same result with OpenSuse. I really need to install Linux but been cracking my head for two days through the forums but in vain.

What am I not doing right?

Comment: I dont have a lenovo T580, but "USB HDD" sounds like a hard disk drive connected over a USB port. Are other boot options listed by your BIOS?

Comment: Thats actually the flash drive other boot options listed are: windows bootmanager; ATA HDD0 and PCI LAN

Comment: Did you make a UFEI format stick. If so is your BIOS in UFEI mode (or if you didnt make a UFEI stick) can you start your BIOS in a non-UFEI mode?

Comment: My bios is in UEFI mode...

Comment: Also ‘usb uefi bios support’ is set to enabled in uefi settings, secure boot disabled; uefi legacy boot is set to ‘both’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i have managed to install ubuntu 18.04 on my Thinkpad T580. The issues addressed were as follows;
Rufus 3.1 asked to download some syslinux files, these files were placed on ‘rufus files’ folder; i had to copy them back to my bootable ubuntu usb (already created using rufus).

- enabled secure boot - this automatically disabled legacy boot and the only option is ‘uefi’ only.
- enabled ‘usb uefi support’
- disbaled ‘quick’ boot to diagnostic
- while creating the bootable usb using rufus, i chose GPT partition type - same as my hard disk partition. Flashdrive file system remains default- fat32.
- also i changed my ‘hp’ flash drive and used ‘sandisk cruzerblade’

This worked flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks! Instead of enabling secure boot, it is possible to set `UEFI only` ;)